# EJB Singleton and JPA optimistic locking throws OptimisticLockException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, singleton, optimistic-locking

I have a problem that relates to an EJB singleton and database locking.

The following class represents an entity for consignment numbers.
It is mandatory that each consignment number is unique. Please note, that this
class has been prepared for optimistic locking by defining the version property.

```
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name = Connote.FIND_NEXT, query = "SELECT c from Connote c WHERE c.consumed = false")
public class Connote implements Serializable {

    /**
    * 
    */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String FIND_NEXT = "Connotes.FindNext";

    @Id
    @Size(max = 15)
    private String connote;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    private Date insertedDate;
    private boolean consumed;
    private Date consumedDate;

    public Connote() {
        super();
    }

    public String getConnote() {
        return connote;
    }

    public void setConnote(String connote) {
        this.connote = connote;
    }

    public Date getInsertedDate() {
        return insertedDate;
    }

    public void setInsertedDate(Date insertedDate) {
        this.insertedDate = insertedDate;
    }

    public boolean isConsumed() {
        return consumed;
    }

    public void setConsumed(boolean consumed) {
        this.consumed = consumed;
    }

    public Date getConsumedDate() {
        return consumedDate;
    }

    public void setConsumedDate(Date consumedDate) {
        this.consumedDate = consumedDate;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }    
}
```

A delivery company provides a set of many thousand consignment numbers, which
will be persisted to the database.

When creating a new freight order, the next "unconsumed" consignment number from this set
should be retrieved and delivered to the requesting service.

The service in this case is an EJB singleton, which provides the service method
"calculateConnoteNumber()". As the ejb class is annotated with "@Lock(LockType.WRITE)"
concurrent access to this method should be prevented. Upon retrieval of the next unconsumed
entity, the flag "consumed" will be flagged to true and the date of consumption will be set.
Finally the updated entity will be merged and the value of connote is being returned.

However, during load testing we experienced  "OptimisticLockExceptions" (avg. 5 from 1000)
when creating new orders.

What I do not understand is, how this is possible as the access to the business method and 
thereby to the transaction should be sequential.

Changing the locking type on persistence layer by setting

```
query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE);
```

works.

To my mind this should not be necessary and optimistic locking should be enough as long as
concurrent access to the business method is prevented.
Did I miss something here?

Environment used: WildFly 8.2.0, MySql 5.7, xa-datasource

```
/**
 * Session Bean implementation class ConnoteCalculatorFacade
 */
@Singleton
@ConcurrencyManagement(ConcurrencyManagementType.CONTAINER)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
@Lock(LockType.WRITE)
public class ConnoteCalculatorFacade {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "some_unit_name")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /**
     * Default constructor.
     */
    public ConnoteCalculatorFacade() {
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("ConnoteCalculatorFacade instantiated!");
        }
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public String calculateConnoteNumber() throws OrderManagementException {
        if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
            logger.info("Retrieving new RS connote!");
        }

        try {
            Query query = this.entityManager.createNamedQuery(Connote.FIND_NEXT);
            query.setMaxResults(1);
            //query.setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE); <-- works when using pessimistic_write

            List<Connote> validConnoteList = query.getResultList();

            if (validConnoteList.size() == 1) {

                Connote connote = validConnoteList.get(0);
                connote.setConsumed(true);
                connote.setConsumedDate(new Date());

                this.entityManager.merge(connote);
                this.entityManager.flush();

                return connote.getConnote();
            } else {
                throw new OrderManagementException(AddressLabelExceptionReason.NO_CONNOTES_AVAILABLE);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error calculating connote number! ",e);
            throw new OrderManagementException(AddressLabelExceptionReason.ERROR_ASSIGNING_CONNOTE);
        }

    }
}
```

**Update**
The service is being consumed by another stateless, local EJB "PDFCreatorFacade", that injects the singleton

```
@EJB
private ConnoteCalculatorFacade connoteCalculator;
...
```

and then calls the method on the singleton in it's (non annotated) business method.

```
public Label createPdfDocument(Label label) throws  OrderManagementException {
    ....
    String connoteNumber = connoteCalculator.calculateConnoteNumber();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Is this a single node system?

Comment: Yes, it is a single node system.

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `calculateConnoteNumber` method... How are you calling (or injecting) your EJB Singleton Definition?

Comment: Updated my answer how the service is being called.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this effect because you have not specified `@ TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)` on your `calculateConnoteNumber` method.

This method is being called by multiple clients which I expect are also EJBs. The first EJB in the call chain will start the transaction and subsequently attempt to commit the transaction, all outside of your concurrency controls.

Comment: SteveC, thanks for your answer. Sorry, I made a mistake when posting the question. The business method was indeed annotated with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW), I removed it when changing to pessimistic locking and forgot to put it back for the question.(updated my question now) Still have OptimisticLockingExceptions (avg. 5/1000) with the testcase provided in my question.

Comment: It would be worthwhile trying WildFly 10.1 instead. You may be encountering a good old fashioned bug in the server implementation